# What does StructMeta mean in an error message, and how do I fix it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, introspection, gtk3

I obtained the error message below in a Python program using Gtk.TreeStore and its associated classes.

```
    TypeError: Expected Gtk.TreeIter, but got StructMeta
```

The error was generated immediately after using using the `Gtk.TreeModelFilter` method `convert_child_iter_to_iter()`, which is supposed to return a `Gtk.TreeIter`. However, the first use of the returned object generates the above message, which does not seem to make any sense to me. What is really confusing, I have been using the reverse process `Gtk.TreeModelFilter.convert_iter_to_child_iter()` with no ill effects at all.

I have trolled the internet looking for some explanation, but so far I have drawn a blank. I can't even decide if this is a Gtk problem, a Python problem, or a Gtk-introspection problem. Is there anyone out there who can shed light on this?